# Meaning of characters in 休戚相关, 患难与共

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, chengyu, saying

I have consulted a dictionary, but am unsure of the meaning of 关 in 休戚相关, 患难与共。

Also I'm not sure about the meaning of 与 in this context.

Comment: also see http://jukuu.com/search.php?q=%E4%BC%91%E6%88%9A%E7%9B%B8%E5%85%B3%2C%E6%82%A3%E9%9A%BE%E4%B8%8E%E5%85%B1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this answer from my Trusty translator. (Had to make her a coffee first!)

休：喜悦，吉利 happiness, luck

戚：忧愁悲哀 worry sadness

相关：related, connected

与共： have in common, we share

Edit: Found this link:

http://www.zybang.com/question/ea2bbea8fb9cc6cf808a4790c7900d44.html

From an old song: Life's joys and life's miseries walk hand in hand and keep each other company.

Think that translates it nicely!